# Snowflake convert rows to columns by delimiter

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table where a specific column has multiple values delimited by '/'. Each row of that column has a different number of values. So I would like to dynamically convert my rows to columns based on the delimiter. Below are few examples from the table.

[image]

I would like to convert the above data to below format

[image]

Comment: See [`split()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split) or [`split_to_table()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table)?

Comment: Why is there not a column named `adheufygvb` or `featured-action:-moves` in the desired output?

Comment: those are the row values

Comment: I have not mentioned any column names here